# How to implement an instant user message and notification system?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am beginning to write my university graduation project and I've chosen to create a web based PHP/MySQL restaurant management system in which there are four categories of users - clients who can make orders, waiters who get clients' orders and do them, cooks who also receive client orders and do them notifying the waiters when the order is done and finally, managers who can add and remove waiters and cooks and edit or update the restaurant menu.

The most important part of the application is the notification system - i.e. when a client asks for a waiter by clicking a button the waiter must get the notification immediately and when a cook is ready with an order and clicks the button to notify the waiter, the waiter should get the notification immediately.

What is the best way to implement such a system using HTML/Javascript/PHP/MySQL?

Comment: "Best" questions are not a good fit for SO's format.

Answer (score 2):

you should look into [WebSockets](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_websocket.htm).  It's a new thing introduced in HTML5.

Basically it allows you to have a two-way communication between the browser and the server all the time.

of course you will need MySQL for database and PHP for server side scripting, Javascript for communication and HTML for rendering the result

Answer (score 1):

Use [longpolling](http://blog.perplexedlabs.com/2009/05/04/php-jquery-ajax-javascript-long-polling/).
You essentially keep a http connection open and "do something" when the server sends data and closes the socket.